# Insert com resultado de um select, como posso fazer isso no Oracle?

Tags: oracle12c

Alguém sabe me dizer como faço para poder gravar no banco de Oracle com Loop.
Quando executo abaixo ele só grava o primeiro registro.

```
INSERT INTO
   BURD_400 (
      NIVEL,
      GRUPO
      ...
   )
SELECT
   BURD_ESTQ_300_MOVIMENTO_60D.NIVEL_ESTRUTURA,
     BURD_ESTQ_300_MOVIMENTO_60D.GRUPO_ESTRUTURA
FROM
   BURD_ESTQ_300_MOVIMENTO_60D
```

Comment: Apresenta algum erro?

Comment: Cara, seu comando está correto. O select retorna quantas linhas?